# Split a dataset into train validation and test - Selection of validation_indices and test_indices

Tags: python, numpy

To split my dataset into train, validation and test I am trying to use the following function:

```
X = df.drop("RISK DECISION", axis = 1).values
y = df["RISK DECISION"].values

def train_validation_test_split(X, y, validation_size = 0.1, test_size = 0.1, random_state = None):
    
    if random_state != None:
        np.random.seed(random_state)
    
    n = X.shape[0]
    
    validation_indices = np.random.choice(n, int(n*validation_size), replace = False)
    test_indices = np.random.choice(n, int(n*test_size), replace = False)
    all_indices = np.concatenate((validation_indices, test_indices))
    
    X_validation = X[validation_indices]
    y_validation = y[validation_indices]
    X_test = X[test_indices]
    y_test = y[test_indices]
    
    X_train = np.delete(X, all_indices, axis = 0)
    y_train = np.delete(y, all_indices, axis = 0)
    
    return(X_train, X_validation, X_test, y_train, y_validation, y_test)
```

The length of the initial dataset is: 34322 records

After applying the function, the sum of the lengths of X_train, X_validation and X_test is greater than the initial length of the dataset.

Perhaps the problem is given by `np.random.choice` with the variables `validation_indices` and `test_indices` possibly containing some identical indices.

How could I solve this problem without modifying `train_validation_test_split` function too much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, duplicate indices will indeed be the problem.
A simple solution would be to draw all_indices together and split the result into validation and test

```
n = X.shape[0]

n_validation = int(n*validation_size)
n_test = int(n*test_size)
all_indices = np.random.choice(n, n_validation+n_test, replace = False)
validation_indices = all_indices[:n_validation]
test_indices = all_indices[n_validation:]

X_validation = X[validation_indices]
y_validation = y[validation_indices]
X_test = X[test_indices]
y_test = y[test_indices]

X_train = np.delete(X, all_indices, axis = 0)
y_train = np.delete(y, all_indices, axis = 0)
```

Since numpy.random.choice seems to give indices in a random order this should be fine.
Just maybe include an assertion to ensure validation_size+test_size<1 (or probably more robust n_validation+n_test<=n)